# Enable Web services in Redmine

Tags: ruby-on-rails, web-services, xml-rpc, redmine, redmine-plugins

Can any one guide me how to enable web services in redmine, specially XML RPC. And a proper way to implement such web service in redmine.

Thanks.
Parthiv

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The REST API appears to have been integrated into the trunk a couple of days ago:

- http://www.redmine.org/projects/redmine/repository/revisions/3310
- http://www.redmine.org/projects/redmine/repository/revisions/3313

Check out Redmine's documentation, with links as to how to use the interface in Ruby and PHP:

- http://www.redmine.org/wiki/redmine/Rest_api

However, I think there's only a REST web service interface now, no SOAP nor XML-RPC.

Comment: thanks for the reply. but i want to implement xml-rpc based web serivces in stable version. I will write out the functions which i need to use on that services, just want to know how to enable basic xml rpc serivces and use it from external xml-rpc client.